# How to display pure HTML using JSONP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, jsonp

We are trying to avoid iframe and instead use javascript, jquery, jsonp and php based web widgets for our displaying content from our cross-domain html site. We want to display the full page as-is within the widget but from all the tutorials we read, its mentioned that we need to provide JSON datatype in order for cross-domain JSONP to work.

Here's what we tried -

Main JS

```
function render() {
  jQuery.getJSON(serverFQDN + '/widget.php?callback=?', {
  install_url: window.location.href
  }, serverResponse);
}

function serverResponse(data) {    
  jQuery(container).html(data.html);
}
```

Widget.php

```
<?php echo $_GET['callback'] ?>({
   "html": "<?php echo 'hello'; ?>"
});
```

We are able to display simple html entities like -

```
<?php   echo $_GET['callback'] ?>({"html": "<li>TEST</li>"
```

});

But not the full page i.e.

```
<?php
$url = "http://localhost/page.html";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$output = json_encode($output);
echo $_GET['callback'] ?>({"html": "<?php echo $output; ?>"
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use cURL or Firebug to check, but I think you are double-JSON-encoding your HTML.

It's also not clear why you write:

```
echo $_GET['callback'] ?>({"html": "<?php echo $output; ?>" });
```

instead of

```
echo $_GET['callback'] ?>({"html": $output });
```

**EDIT**: Never mind, I have it.  You are JSON-encoding just to Javascript-encode -- but you have an extra set of quotation marks!

if $output is `"<li>TEST</li>"`, then the file you are creating is

```
 jsonpCallback({"html" : ""<li>TEST</li>""});
```

Uh, I think.  Like I said, use cURL or Firebug to check the actual output.